Drawing a tree of given depth
I can easily draw a binary tree of given depth by adapting the example from the tikz manual, for instance like
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=4mm,level/.style={sibling distance=8mm/#1},scale=3]
\coordinate
    child foreach \x in {0,1}
        {child foreach \y in {0,1}
            {child foreach \z in {0,1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which gives

However, I would like that code to be "scalable", that is, elegantly adaptable for "any" tree depth, something looking like
\coordinate
    \foreach \x in {0,\depth}
        child foreach \y in {0,1};

which doesn't work (and I know why it doesn't work: "expansion and stuff").
The tikz manual doesn't give insight on how to do it, in particular, in the section about "making trees grow". I also don't quite know my way around the forest package, and couldn't find similar modular examples in the documentation.

I'd recommend using one of the specialist packages for trees based on tikz rather than plain tikz. forest would be my choice, but far from the only possibility. the syntax is then more compact and forest is easy to automate.

for \foreach \x in {0,\depth} you would need to expand \depth first as \foreach is fussy about that ;). or you can use the utility key to expand first, I think.

I understand why what I propose doesn't work like that ;-) it's just I don't know a way around, and I don't know how to handle the forest package (I'm currently reading the doc)

Feel free to add more keywords to this search to better understand forest by example. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forest

A non-automated example with forest:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  binary/.style={%
    for tree={%
      coordinate,
      l sep'=4mm,
      s sep/.process={Ow+P{level}{9mm/(#1+1)}},
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  binary,
  [[[[][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


l sep adjusts the level distance; s sep adjusts the separation between the child nodes.
Automation
The following shows steps to automate the above. The first three examples produce the same tree using increasing automaticity. The final example illustrates how to vary the output and customise the tree.
The base case from above:
\begin{forest}
  binary,
  [[[[][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]]
\end{forest}

This uses a style, but it doesn't automate production of the tree structure. The style is as above,
  binary/.style={%
    for tree={%
      coordinate,
      l sep'=4mm,
      s sep/.process={Ow+P{level}{9mm/(#1+1)}},
    },
  },

The next example uses a style which automates production of the structure additionally.
\begin{forest}
  binary tree=2,
  []
\end{forest}


This style is a bit more sophisticated:
  binary tree/.style={%

We delay application of custom formatting because most of the nodes we want to apply the formatting to probably don't yet exist.
    before typesetting nodes={binary},

We delay this because we don't have a leaf node until after the first pass.
    delay={%

Get the current number of levels.
      tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{leaves},

Compare that with the requested number, which is passed as an argument to the style (#1). If we have fewer levels, we add one.
      while={>R_<{tempcounta}{#1}}{%

Update the count.
        tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{leaves},

Add the new level - two nodes for each leaf.
        for leaves={%
          append={[]},
          append={[]},
        },

Create the nodes so they are available as leaves for the next loop, if needed.
        do dynamics,
      },
    },
  },

The third case uses more concise input still:
\binarytree{2}


We define \binarytree[]{} to take an optional argument, which is intended to adjust the formatting, and a mandatory one, which should be a positive integer specifying the number of levels.
\NewDocumentCommand \binarytree { O {} m }
{%
  \begin{forest}

Apply the style.
    binary tree=#2,

Override binary by applying any optional formatting afterwards.
    before typesetting nodes={%
      delay={%
        #1,
      },
    }

We need to create the root node or there is nothing to append children to.
    []
  \end{forest}%
}

So a customised tree might be produced with, say,
\binarytree[for tree={l sep'+=1mm,s sep'=3mm,}]{4}


\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730905/
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  binary tree/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={binary},
    delay={%
      tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{leaves},
      while={>R_<{tempcounta}{#1}}{%
        tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{leaves},
        for leaves={%
          append={[]},
          append={[]},
        },
        do dynamics,
      },
    },
  },
  binary/.style={%
    for tree={%
      coordinate,
      l sep'=4mm,
      s sep/.process={Ow+P{level}{9mm/(#1+1)}},
    },
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand \binarytree { O {} m }
{%
  \begin{forest}
    binary tree=#2,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      delay={%
        #1,
      },
    }
    []
  \end{forest}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  binary,
  [[[[][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  binary tree=2,
  []
\end{forest}
\binarytree{2}
\binarytree[for tree={l sep'+=1mm,s sep'=3mm,}]{4}
\end{document}


I can automate this later if there's any interest. E.g. you could just have a \bintree{} macro which produced the tree given the number of levels.

I'm have interest. Actually, it's my only interest : create a complete binary tree of depth k (where k is given)

why the downvote? (rhetorical question, obviously, since I'm the one person I know can't have downvoted it.)

@R.Absil please see edited answer above.

It's really great. I adapted your code to explicitly draw nodes (circle,very thick,color=gray,minimum size=20pt,draw,edge=gray)
which looks nice, except for the root node. Any idea what's wrong?

And sorry about the downvote: I set it at first when the answer wasn't automated, when that's what I only asked for. 't'was bratty and harsh, I admit, and I'm sorry. I fixed that ;-) . Your explanations are also wonderfully well written. I'm sure this post will be useful to many other users.

I added for tree={parent anchor={}} right after the \begin{forest} of \NewDocumentCommand \binarytree and it looks just right. Thanks for the help.
